# Backpropagation with tensor contraction

Tags: calculus, tensors

I understand backpropagation for scalar variables, but I am confused when the variables are tensors. For example, if one variable is a matrix and another is a vector, then the derivative of one with respect to another is a tensor. No computer, so I have to include an image of what I mean:

[image: backprop]

I know very little about tensors or tensor contraction, so I'm not sure how this is normally resolved in automatic differentiation algorithms. **How do I compute the tensor contraction needed at the bottom of the image?**